# Is it correct and natural to say "learn with a textbook" meaning to learn something using a textbook?

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct and natural to say *learn with a textbook* meaning to learn something using a textbook? For example:

> It's as useful to **learn** a foreign language **with a textbook** as to learn it commuicating with people.

If it sounds off, how would you say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s actually fine, but I feel that “from a textbook” would be slightly more idiomatic.

I’d also make a few other changes to your phrasing so that it would be:

> It's as useful to learn a foreign language **from** a textbook as **it is** to learn **one by** communicating with people.